# Prometheus query，How to find the percentage of each line

Tags: prometheus

I have the following data: a counter for each service instance identified by the ip.

```
ribbon_rule_count_total{way="round_robin",service="order_server",ip="101.141.108.119"}  109056
ribbon_rule_count_total{way="round_robin",service="order_server",ip="101.141.108.120"}  109057
ribbon_rule_count_total{way="round_robin",service="order_server",ip="101.141.108.121"}  109056
ribbon_rule_count_total{way="round_robin",service="user_server",ip="101.136.34.198"}    109056
ribbon_rule_count_total{way="round_robin",service="user_server",ip="101.136.34.197"}    109056
```

I want to display **the ratio of the metric for each ip relatively to the service** like below.

```
order_server-101.141.108.119   33%
order_server-101.141.108.120   33%
order_server-101.141.108.121   33%
user_server-101.136.34.198     50%
user_server-101.136.34.197     50%
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to compute the percentage of the metrics per ip over a service, you need to:

1. [sum](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators) the metrics ignoring the ip

   ```
   sum(ribbon_rule_count_total) without(ip)
   ```

   This will give you the metrics:

   ```
   ribbon_rule_count_total{way="round_robin",service="order_server"}  318269
   ribbon_rule_count_total{way="round_robin",service="user_server"}   218112
   ```
2. be able to divide each metric with [one to many](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) matching expression

   ```
   ribbon_rule_count_total / ignoring(ip) group_left sum(ribbon_rule_count_total) without(ip)
   ```

This should give you what you expected in your question - with the percentage value added in.

```
100 * ribbon_rule_count_total / ignoring(ip) group_left sum(ribbon_rule_count_total) without(ip)
```

This should be enough for the computation. I you really want a display similar to your example, your can [join the labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_join):

```
avg(label_join(<precedent expression>, name, "-", service, ip)) by (name)
```